# Material-ui show pointer cursor when hovering over TextField

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Material-ui/ReactJS newbie question. I'm trying to show a pointer cursor when hovering over a Material-ui TextField but having a difficult time doing so. It makes use of 'cursor: text' by default.  I've been able to successfully change the textfield background color on hover but adding "cursor: pointer !important" does no good. I've tried making use of className, class, style (inline), but I'm certain I'm not doing something correctly. Material-ui has a demo illustrating how to change textfield styling on hover and focused at [https://codesandbox.io/s/p7uwn?file=/demo.js][1]  where I have also tried changing the cursor to a pointer on hover but still no luck. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { TextField, NoSsr } from '@material-ui/core';

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  label.Mui-focused {
    color: green;
  }
  .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    fieldset {
      border-color: red;
    }
    &:hover fieldset {
      border-color: yellow;
      cursor: pointer !important;
    }
    &.Mui-focused fieldset {
      border-color: green;
    }
  }
`;

export default function GlobalClassName() {
  return (
    <NoSsr>
      <StyledTextField label="Deterministic" variant="outlined" id="deterministic-outlined-input" />
    </NoSsr>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using

```
<TextField sx={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} />
```

did not work for me, instead, I needed to specify it as

```
<TextField sx={{ input: { cursor: 'pointer' } }}
```

which did affect the desired change.

Comment: But why you should use input? is this something inside textfield design called input?

Answer (score 4):

Or just literally put cursor:pointer into its css, either in-line as `<Component style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>` or `<Component sx={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>` or in its styled component css. This will automatically change your mouse `onHover`, and the top answer here is way over the top. Just add `cursor: 'pointer'` to the component's css.

Comment: <Textfield sx={{cursor: 'pointer'}}> doesn't work for me. Only with <TextField sx={{ input: { cursor: 'pointer' } }}

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick browser inspection gave the CSS component we need to target. It's

> .MuiOutlinedInput-input

Just giving it a

> cursor: pointer;

property will solve your problem.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { TextField, NoSsr } from '@material-ui/core';

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  label.Mui-focused {
    color: green;
  }
  .MuiOutlinedInput-input {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .MuiOutlinedInput-root {
    fieldset {
      border-color: red;
    }
    &:hover fieldset {
      border-color: blue;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    &.Mui-focused fieldset {
      border-color: green;
    }
  }
`;

export default function GlobalClassName() {
  return (
    <NoSsr>
      <StyledTextField label="Deterministic" variant="outlined" id="deterministic-outlined-input" />
    </NoSsr>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But applying cursor:pointer to that class essentially applies the cursor:pointer all of the time, not just on hover. Ideally, I'm trying to apply the cursor:pointer on hover only.

Comment: Hover and focused are two different states. Applying cursor:pointer to "MuiOutlinedInput-input" will show a pointer for both hover and focused state. I only want to show pointer on hover state only.

Comment: Adding :hover and :focused selector and giving them cursor properties will solve the problem. `.MuiOutlinedInput-input:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .MuiOutlinedInput-input:focus {
    cursor: auto;
  }`